# Service doesn't work offline in Angular after deploying to git hub pages

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

I am trying to create PWA in angular 8. Service worker works well on offline mode on local.
I created a production build using `ng build --prop --base-href https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/` . It is not working in offline mode. even It is not creating the `.APK` file after clicking on `Add to home screen`. I tried each and every thing but nothing worked.

> Angular version is 7.1.4
>
> PWA version is 0.7.4

**here is my manifest.json file**

```
{
  "name": "service-worker-demo",
  "short_name": "service-worker-demo",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

**here is my ngsw.json file**

```
{
  "configVersion": 1,
  "index": "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "urls": [
        "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/favicon.ico",
        "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/index.html",
        "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/main.007e90047975087c8201.js",
        "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/polyfills.3bfd66addbd0d2814591.js",
        "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js",
        "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css"
      ],
      "patterns": []
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "urls": [
        "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
        "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
        "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
        "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
        "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
        "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
        "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
        "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-96x96.png"
      ],
      "patterns": []
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [],
  "hashTable": {
    "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-128x128.png": "dae3b6ed49bdaf4327b92531d4b5b4a5d30c7532",
    "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-144x144.png": "b0bd89982e08f9bd2b642928f5391915b74799a7",
    "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-152x152.png": "7479a9477815dfd9668d60f8b3b2fba709b91310",
    "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-192x192.png": "1abd80d431a237a853ce38147d8c63752f10933b",
    "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-384x384.png": "329749cd6393768d3131ed6304c136b1ca05f2fd",
    "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-512x512.png": "559d9c4318b45a1f2b10596bbb4c960fe521dbcc",
    "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png": "c457e56089a36952cd67156f9996bc4ce54a5ed9",
    "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/assets/icons/icon-96x96.png": "3914125a4b445bf111c5627875fc190f560daa41",
    "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/favicon.ico": "84161b857f5c547e3699ddfbffc6d8d737542e01",
    "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/index.html": "908fc9ad22a589fe693265fb1f435bda20f1f349",
    "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/main.007e90047975087c8201.js": "bb43944f676c6e58ee6189240dd7b516533e310f",
    "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/polyfills.3bfd66addbd0d2814591.js": "6946e10a03311677a01490b8e91741668e64e17e",
    "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js": "b62956c2192bfe5516d6374e753773901ed50ec5",
    "https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/styles.3ff695c00d717f2d2a11.css": "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709"
  },
  "navigationUrls": [
    {
      "positive": true,
      "regex": "^\\/.*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*\\.[^/]*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*__[^/]*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*__[^/]*\\/.*$"
    }
  ]
}
```

You can test it on this link https://tejindermakkar786.github.io/angular-pwa/

I really need a help.

Thanks

Comment: Installs fine on Chrome desktop. Could be something with github hosting (wild guess), you could try uploading it to a free HTTPS site like https://Glitch.me

Comment: Also is this just a typo "ng build --prop" should be "ng build --prod" ?

Comment: I just tried it on an android device. Installed as expected and works offline. Are you testing with a device that you were using while developing? If so, are you sure you totally uninstalled any previous tests and TOTALLY cleared out your browser cache?

Comment: I tried with the link he provided and indeed it does not work offline. @Tejinder Singh: I wrote a guide, where I describe step-by-step how to create a PWA with offline capabilities with Angular:  https://dev.to/paco_ita/create-progressive-web-apps-with-angular-workbox-pwa-builder-step-4-27d#angular, maybe you can have a look at it and see if you missed anything in your setup.